# Embed variables in a string

Tags: java, string, variables, text

I want to use a variable in a string but I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
private AbstractAction tester = new AbstractAction("test love match") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        match.setText("text \n text (VARIABLE) text \n text");  // <--  
    }
};
```

Comment: What language are you talking about? Add it as a tag to your question.

Comment: Java, at a guess. But please don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), especially if you have multiple variable that you would like to use in this fashion within a single string:

```
match.setText(String.format("text \n text %s text \n text", variable));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
match.setText("text \n text "  + yourText + " text \n text");
```

If you want to use a String from your Resources, you can do it this way:

```
String yourText = res.getString(R.string.nameofyourtext);
match.setText(yourText);
```

This way, you can edit and manage your Strings more easily within your strings.xml (res/values/strings.xml)

Comment: The problem with solution is that it doesn't allow you to externalize strings easily ;)

Comment: What do you mean by externalize?

Comment: [Externalize strings](http://www.coderanch.com/t/580226/java/java/String-Externalization-reasons) means putting stings in a separate file, for example to support multiple languages (translations).

Comment: That was not really part of the question and is actually possible (to get a String from res and put in into a String-object)

Comment: True, it's not part of the question, but it helps decide which is the best answer. And yes, it's feasible, but more complicated than other answers here. Also, you're creating 3 different String objects and concatenating them. All of this definitely makes arshajii's answer (for example) way better in all aspects.

Comment: The other answers use the exact same method - concatinating a String-object with a hardcoded string - but i´ll add it

Comment: No. For example arshajii's answer does not. And avoids all the mentioned problems with your answer.

Comment: "Also, you're creating 3 different String objects..." That´s a point though, I didn´t even know that
But he´s using a String just like I do, and you can externalize them the exact same way - it´s just a different way of concatination. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: One string and he can externalize it as a whole. You need to externalize 2 different strings with no reason since they're part of the same message. Don't get me wrong, your solution/answer is OK, but the other solution is better. I hope you get the point ;)

Comment: But he is using two strings, one hardcoded and one as an object. For externalizing, you dont hardcode anything, but then there would be no concatination, and that was the original question.

Comment: Right, my mistake. Then you're using 3 strings and the same problems still apply. For example, this is the string: `"I need to eat %s tomorrow"` which in your case would be `"I need to eat " + whatevervariable + " tomorrow"`. In your case, you need to externalize `"I need to eat "`, `whatevervariable` and `" tomorrow"`. This string externalization makes no sense. What is `" tomorrow"`? And not to talk about translating issues when for example `" tomorrow"` has to be before the verb for some grammar issues of the language. I think you got the point ;)

Comment: Yes, but like i said, this example was ONLY meant to show how to concatinate. For externalisation I would take the string as a whole and put it into Strings.xml - that´s what you want to say, right?

Comment: Yes, but sorry, the question is **NOT** about how to concatenate. *"I want to use a variable in a string but I don't know how"* is not *"I don't know how to concatenate"*. It's about how to replace a substring with a variable. And I'm just pointing flaws in your answer. Again, arshajii's answer is better in all aspects for the question being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable:

```
private String variable = "your text here";
private AbstractAction tester = new AbstractAction("test love match") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            match.setText("text \n text " + variable + " text \n text");

            }
    };
```

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is **the concatenation operator “+”**.

Java code :

```
"Hello, " + name + "."
```

If the String `name` contains “Dave”, this Java code will give the String :

“Hello, Dave.”

[ In Java, we don't talk about *variables*, we talk about *objects*. ]